# How to make Team City check out the latest revision of a branch - regardles if a tag exists

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

For some reason, TC is no longer detecting changes to the development branch after we tagged a release. Up until last Friday, there were no tags, and TC had been building fine up until that point. We then added a tag to mark the end of a spring and following that, no changes are picked up by Team City. Triggering a manual run only checks out the same revision that was tagged. I don't see why tagging a release should affect the VCS procedure, given that nothing change there.

Relevant output from build log

```
[10:18:29][Compute revision for 'app-develop branch'] Upper limit revision: 1ec51e6c701548753678c18c20e24c87a6c189f7
[10:18:29][Compute revision for 'app-develop branch'] Latest commit attached to build configuration: 1ec51e6c701548753678c18c20e24c87a6c189f7
[10:18:29][Compute revision for 'app-develop branch'] Computed revision: 1ec51e6c701548753678c18c20e24c87a6c189f7
```

When I manually ssh into the CI server and go to the build directory I see that the remote `develop` branch can be seen, but the local is not updated:

```
* cf2c86a - (origin/develop) Handle special users when formatting names (67 minutes ago) <Carl-Erik Kopseng>
* 70cadf0 - Fix bug in formatting (82 minutes ago) <Carl-Erik Kopseng>
* 8f24c0d - Move user formatting util over to domain class (83 minutes ago) <Carl-Erik Kopseng>
* 1ec51e6 - (HEAD, tag: sprint-15-demo, develop) Merge pull request #826 from mycomp/nim-605 (7 weeks ago) <Carl-Erik Kopseng>
```

[image: config]

[image: trigger section]

Comment: What do you have set as a branch filter in the "Triggers" part of your TC configuration?

Comment: Also, how is your "Branch Specification" configured in TC's VCS Root settings?

Comment: @Amy Thanks for the feedback. I attached a screenshot. I don't have a branch filter.

Comment: Hm, I have `refs/heads/develop` set as my default branch.  I don't know if that would affect anything though.

Comment: I'll try changing it ...

Comment: Hey, that seemed to be it! I have no idea why, though ...

Comment: In that case, I'll write that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll add another answer, as the one by @Amy *seemingly* worked in one situation, but not for another project. This other project already had the default branch set to the right (default) value of `refs/heads/master`.

What finally worked for me was the [tedious solution found on the TC community](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205450530-Not-latest-revision-of-branch-is-builded?page=1#community_comment_360000074399):

- Detach the existing VCS root
- Create a new one with the exact same settings

Yes, that shouldn't make a difference, but it did.

I suspect the joker of the puzzle might be that we reverted back to a previous configuration last week. That made the build counter incorrect (DB vs config), which might have fuzzed with the concept of historic builds and all that jazz. In any case, certainly a bug from the user perspective.

Comment: Indeed, while this still happens with latest version of TeamCity Professional 2018.2.4 (build 61678) -- this solution/workaround works to get Teamcity to get un-stuck from some old commit and build with latest version of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Set your default branch to `refs/heads/develop` instead of `develop`.

I *suspect* what's happening is it cannot find your default branch, since `develop` isn't a "valid" branch specification, so it searches for other branches and tags.  It finds one, and uses that.  This wasn't an issue when no other branches/tags existed.